# How to get real time username when any user login without clicking on button using signalr?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have application on which I get all username when someone login but I need to click the button to show all users,I want to show all user on real time as soon as someone login.However I am able to logout user on real time.
This below code working well for getting username on click button and real time logout users.

```
 [Authorize]
public class AuthHub : Hub
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> ActiveUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);


    public IEnumerable<string> GetConnectedUsers()
    {

        return ActiveUsers.Where(x => {

            lock (x.Value.ConnectionIds)
            {

                return !x.Value.ConnectionIds.Contains(Context.ConnectionId, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            }

        }).Select(x => x.Key);
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {


        string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        var user = ActiveUsers.GetOrAdd(userName, _ => new User
        {
            Name = userName,
            ConnectionIds = new HashSet<string>()
        });

        lock (user.ConnectionIds)
        {

            user.ConnectionIds.Add(connectionId);

        }

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    private User GetUser(string username)
    {

        User user;
        ActiveUsers.TryGetValue(username, out user);

        return user;
    }

    public void forceLogOut(string to)
    {

        User receiver;
        if (ActiveUsers.TryGetValue(to, out receiver))
        {

            User sender = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);

            IEnumerable<string> allReceivers;
            lock (receiver.ConnectionIds)
            {
                allReceivers = receiver.ConnectionIds.Concat(receiver.ConnectionIds);
            }

            foreach (var cid in allReceivers)
            {
                Clients.Client(cid).Signout();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> client side code

```
 $(function () {

        var chat = $.connection.authHub;

        chat.client.Signout = function () {
            $('#logoutForm').submit();
            $.connection.hub.stop();
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            console.log("working");
            function PopulateActiveUsers() {

                $("#usersTable").empty();
                chat.server.getConnectedUsers().done(function (users) {
                    console.log("working");
                    $.each(users, function (i, username) {
                        $("#usersTable").append("<tr><th scope='row'>" + (i + 1) + "</th><td>" + username + "</td><td><a href='javascript:void(0)' data-user='" + username + "' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-logout'>Logout User</a></td></tr>");
                    });
                });
            }

            $("#displayActiveUsers").on("click", function () {
                PopulateActiveUsers();
            });

            $('body').on('click', 'a.btn-logout', function () {
                var username = $(this).attr('data-user');
                chat.server.forceLogOut(username);
            });

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would add that same method you call from the client to fire during the OnConnected() event. Example:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
  //Get your list of users however you do that now

  //Send back to all clients
  Client.All.yourClientMethod(users);
}
```

In your client you just need a client side method to receive the data and process it just as you do now.

Comment: bro still i need to refresh the page to show login user

Comment: No. When any user logs in, the OnConnected() event fires. Inside that event you get all your current logged in users and send that to all connected users using Client.All and your client method will receive that update. No refresh needed. Please review - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

Comment: bro thank you very much I have solved my problem getting logic from your code

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by doing some modification in my code like so

```
public void GetConnectedUsers()
    {

        Clients.All.getConnectedUsers(ActiveUsers.Where(x =>
        {

            lock (x.Value.ConnectionIds)
            {

                return x.Value.ConnectionIds.Contains(Context.ConnectionId, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            }

        }).Select(x => x.Key).ToList());

        //return Clients.All(ActiveUsers.Select(x => x.Key).ToList());

    }
```

//client side code

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                
        
                chat.server.getConnectedUsers().done(function (users) { });
    });

chat.client.getConnectedUsers = function (users) {
                $.each(users, function (i, username) {                   
                            $("#usersTable").append("<tr><th scope='row'>" + (i + 1) + "</th><td>" + username + "</td><td><a href='javascript:void(0)' data-user='" + username + "' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-logout'>Logout User</a></td></tr>");
                });
            };
```